# Демонстрация MVCC Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Нужно продемонстрировать работу MVCC в Postgresql с помощью нескольких параллельных сессий, работающих с одними и теми же данными в таблице.

Можете подсказать, как это сделать или скинуть ссылку на ресурс, объясняющий это?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-mvcc-multi-version-concurrency-control-work/

Comment: Это немного не то, что мне нужно. Мне нужна не теория, а демонстрация работа